# fs.stats Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I need to compare the sizes of two files. If the first is greater than the second, then it returns one; if the sizes are equal, it returns zero, otherwise -1.
And I wrote a test that I can’t pass:

```
test('compareFileSizes', (done) => {
  const filepath1 = `${__dirname}/../Makefile`;
  const filepath2 = `${__dirname}/test.js`;
  compareFileSizes(filepath1, filepath2, (_error1, result) => {
    expect(result).toBe(-1);
    done();
  });
});
```

My code:

```
import fs from 'fs';
export const compareFileSizes = (file1, file2, cb) => {
  fs.stat(file1, (_err, stats1) => {
    let size1 = stats1.size;
    cb(_err, size1);
  fs.stat(file2, (_err, stats2) => {
    let size2 = stats2.size;
    cb(_err, size2);
    if(size1 > size2){
      return Math.sign(1);
    } else if(size1 === size2){
      return Math.sign(0);
    } else{
      return Math.sign(-1);
    }
  })
  })
```

The function does not return what is needed. Which way to go or how to cut the algorithm right?
};

Comment: maybe try simplifying your code with `fs.statSync` to avoid any unexpected callback behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to block the thread of execution, then you cannot use `fs.statSync`, with the help of callbacks your code will look like this:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

export const compareFileSizes = (file1, file2, cb) => {
    fs.stat(file1, (error, stats1) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return cb(error);
        }

        const size1 = stats1.size;

        fs.stat(file2, (err, stats2) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return cb(err);
            }

            const size2 = stats2.size;
            const result = Math.sign(size1 - size2);

            return cb(null, result);
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So woudn't this be much easier

```
import fs from 'fs';
export const compareFileSizes = (file1, file2) => {
  let size1 = fs.statSync(file1).size;
  let size2 = fs.statSync(file2).size;
  return Math.sign(size1 - size2);
})
```

no callback needed at all ?

Comment: definitely needed